# C# PuppeteerSharp Блокируется перенаправление с Cloudflare Waiting Room

Tags: c#, .net, puppeteer, веб-скрейпинг

Сайт, который я пытаюсь исследовать с Puppeteer, защищён страницей Cloudflare, которая анализирует браузер. Создаётся впечатление, что существует некоторая проблема при использовании `GoToAsync` - зал ожидания Cloudflare бесконечно обновляется, но доступ не блокирует. Стоит только закрыть приложение (= закрыть CDP-сессию), перенаправление сразу завершается успешно. Если открывать вкладку вручную и забивать URL-адрес, проверка так же проходит успешно. Либо Cloudflare как то понимает что существует CDP-сессия и браузер автоматизирован, либо в Puppeteer есть проблема. Как можно это понять?

Кроме того, если после открытия браузера создать новую вкладку и загрузить страницу, далее продолжить выполнение со строчки `IPage page = await PuppeteerHeadful.NewPageAsync();`, то проверка будет пройдена успешно.

```
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync();
PuppeteerHeadful = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions {
    Headless = false,
    Devtools = false,
    Browser = SupportedBrowser.Chrome,
    DefaultViewport = null,
    Args = new[] {
        "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled"
    }
});

IPage page = await PuppeteerHeadful.NewPageAsync();
await page.GoToAsync(url);
```

- URL для примера: https://www.vindecoderz.com/EN/check-lookup/WVWMP7AN2BE710202
- Версия .NET: 6.0
- Версия PuppeteerSharp: 14.0.0

Comment: попробуйте https://github.com/Overmiind/Puppeteer-sharp-extra

Comment: Проблема скорее всего не в детекте, а именно в работе самого браузера - перенаправление блокируется